# MySQL: foreign key constraint not enforced

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `client`
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(200),
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
   INDEX(`customer_id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

Then I ran the following:

```
INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES ('Customer1');
```

Now the table customer contains name: Customer1, id: 1

Then I ran this:

```
INSERT INTO client (name, customer_id) VALUES ('Client of Customer1',34);
```

It was supposed to fail, but it inserted successfully. Why is that?

This is on MySQL 5.1 on Linux Mint.

Comment: Are both tables InnoDB tables?

Comment: strange. i am using 5.5.10 on Windows and the constraint was enforced.

Comment: How can I verify if they are InnoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a `show create table customer`. It'll show the engine used at the end of the dumped `create table` statement. If they're showing as MyISAM, that engine doesn't suport foreign keys. The FK definitions are parsed, but otherwise ignored.

To force a table to be Inno DB, which DOES support foren keys, you have to do

```
CREATE TABLE ( ... blah blah blah ...) TYPE=InnoDB;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^--force InnoDB type
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be an engine issue, just to be sure add the engine when creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `client`
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(200),
  `customer_id` INT NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
   INDEX(`customer_id`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer`(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```